# What are keyboard shortcuts for Lasso, Handtool and select edit tool for OneNote2013?

Tags: keyboard, shortcuts, microsoft-onenote

As Title, I am using Traditional Chinese version which tools' name might not be the same as I mentioned.

Or How can I assign keyboard shortcut for different tools? btw I have no idea why Microsoft loves to produce software frustrating user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pressing `Alt+D+T/L/H/E` for Ttype , Lasso, Hand, Eraser Tools correspondingly

You can always access tools on Ribbon by first pressing `Alt` then follow guides shown